# i want to print the following data on table in ci

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

basically i am working on a project in table had courses id are appear and under these course id student name are appears.
You can see into this image

[image]

the data are fetch but am not able to place perfectly. can any one help me??

```
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="row main-center"> 
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <h4 style="Text-align:center">Teacher Name : <span></span></h4> 
      </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="row main">
      <div class="main-login main-center"> 
         <table class="table table-dark"> 
           <thead> 
             <tr> 
              <?php foreach ($mydata as $data) {?> 
                <th scope="col"><?php echo $data->COURSE_ID?></th> 
                <!-- <th scope="col">Status</th> <th scope="col">Action</th> --> 
              <?php }?> 
             </tr> 
           </thead>
           <tbody> 
             <?php foreach ($mydata as $data) {?> 
             <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data->FIRST_NAME ." ".$data->LAST_NAME; ?></td> 
             </tr> <?php } ?>
           </tbody>
      </table>
     <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
  </div>
```

---

---

```
 thats my code of html 

$query = $this->db->query("
   SELECT teacher_registration.COURSE_ID, 
   student.FIRST_NAME,
   student.LAST_NAME 
   FROM teacher_registration left outer JOIN student_registration ON 
   teacher_registration.COURSE_ID = student_registration.COURSE_ID 
   left outer JOIN student ON 
   student.OEN_NUMBER = student_registration.OEN_NUMBER 
   WHERE 
   teacher_registration.REG_ID =".$id
);
```

---

thats my query which are fetched the data.

Comment: Can we have better indentation pls?

Comment: How do you want them placed, on same line?

Comment: What is the desire HTML output? Can you mock one?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="container"> 
   <div class="row main-center"> 
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <h4 style="Text-align:center">Teacher Name : <span></span></h4> 
      </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="row main">
      <div class="main-login main-center"> 
         <table class="table table-dark"> 
           <thead> 
             <tr> 
              <?php foreach ($mydata as $data) {?> 
                <th scope="col"><?php echo $data->COURSE_ID?></th> 
                <!-- <th scope="col">Status</th> <th scope="col">Action</th> --> 
              <?php }?> 
             </tr> 
           </thead>
           <tbody> 

             <tr>
<?php foreach ($mydata as $data) {?> 
                <td><?php echo $data->FIRST_NAME ." ".$data->LAST_NAME; ?></td> 

             </tr> 
           </tbody>
      </table>
     <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
  </div>
```

loop must be inside `<tr>` to get out put in same line

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the table cell (td) instead if the row...

```
<tbody> 
  <tr>
     <?php foreach ($mydata as $data) {?> 
         <td><?php echo $data->FIRST_NAME ." ".$data->LAST_NAME; ?></td> 
     <?php } ?>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```